# Where did the snowclone "X-Complete" come from?

Tags: etymology, history, snowclones

I'm familiar with the phrases "[Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)" and "[NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness)" from the field of computing science. (Along with less common variations similar to NP-complete such as EXP-complete or PSPACE-complete.) I have also heard a particular programming language called Idris described as "Pac-man-complete" meaning that it is feasible to implement the game Pac-Man in it, since it has qualities in common with previous languages where that would not be so. I recently learned that the phrase "[UV-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_completion)" has [also seen use](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78381/what-is-the-definition-of-a-uv-complete-theory) to describe theories in physics.

At this point I think it's fair to say that the phrase "X-complete" has become a snowclone. I'm wondering if it is known where the snowclone originated. I might guess that it originated with either Turing-complete or NP-complete, since those are the variations I heard first, but I have no other evidence for that.